# How can I fix this: Uncaught Error: [ensureSignedIn] no signIn route configured

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm getting this error: `Uncaught Error: [ensureSignedIn] no signIn route configured!`

I can't find anything about it on google.

I have this in at the bottom of my routes.js in common code (server and client):

```
FlowRouter.triggers.enter([AccountsTemplates.ensureSignedIn], 
                          {except: ["templateA", "templateB"]});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm sure you need more information. What shall I provide to help you help me?

**Additional info:**

I have `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');` in the server directory. For 'fun' I decided to add it above the ensureSignedIn trigger and I got the following error:

```
Error: Route already configured!
    at [object Object].AccountsTemplates.configureRoute (packages/useraccounts_flow-routing.js:108:11)
```

That is 'funny' because without adding that line the error is that the route is NOT already configured.

Comment: I think you need to have your own route 'signIn' configured (i.e. a page where the user logs in) if you want to use that option (ensureSignedIn).

Comment: I also have `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');` in a file in the server directory. This was all that was needed in the Iron Router version, but now maybe something else is needed since I moved to Flow Router?

Comment: Yes, but do you actually have the signIn route defined? e.g. `FlowRouter.route('/signIn', { name: 'signIn', ... ` ?

Comment: No. I didn't notice that in the documentation. What would be the "action: ..." of that route definition?

Comment: Something like rendering your login page, maybe?   `BlazeLayout.render('yourMainLayout', {content: 'login'});`

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/flow-routing says:
"This will set up the sign in route with a full-page form at /sign-in:
`AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');`"

Comment: Ah ok. But you mentioned that is configured on the server side. Shouldn't it be in the client code? I had problems with code on the wrong side before with meteor and Accounts.

Comment: I moved it to the client directory and got this error:
    `AccountsTemplates.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'siteName' of undefined`

Comment: Are you importing your `routes.js` file at `startup`? What's your directory structure?

Comment: I am not importing my routes.js. I have it in common code. I have what Meteor provided. client, server, lib, private, public.

Comment: Not 100% clear what's going on, but note that `AccountsTemplates.configure({})` must be configured before you define your routes with `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute({})` - https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/flow-routing#blaze-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AccountsTemplates.configure` and `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute` stuff needs to be on the **client**

The `Accounts.emailTemplates` stuff needs to be on the **server**.